# Codeigniter jQuery file upload not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

PHP Code:

```
$files = json_decode($this->input->post('Image'));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
```

jQuery code:

```
var image = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= $("#removeimagefield").attr('data-id'); i++){
    image.push($("#imageupload"+i).val());
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(image));
```

HTML code:

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" name="formname" id="formname"  method="post" action="">
    <input type="file" class="default" id="imageupload1">
</form>
```

AJAX Function:

```
  addproperty = {Image: JSON.stringify(image)}
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: formsubmission,
    data: addproperty,
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

Console message:

```
["C:\\fakepath\\abhishek.jpg","C:\\fakepath\\krunal.jpg","C:\\fakepath\\nitin.jpg"]
```

I am trying to uploading image file to Codeigniter Controller. but when I am printing value of $files. than it displaying empty array.

Comment: where's your code in the controller? :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and get your file in controller using simple $_FILES['img_file']['file_name']

```
   $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    var file_name = $('#id_file_input').prop('files')[0];
                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append('img_file', file_data);
                    $('#vid_file').prop('disabled', true);
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Controller/function_name', 
                        dataType: 'text', 
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: form_data,
                        type: 'post',
                          success: function (response) {

                        }
                    });
                    });
```

Comment: man everything are dynamic it is a not a static. people can add new field for image.